# Q: Bluetooth automatically turns on

Tags: bluetooth

i am using 0.4.1 loki, and every time the PC awake its bluetooth is turned on. Is there a way to completely disable bluetooth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable bluetooth using the following command in terminal

> sudo rfkill block bluetooth

To disable it completely, run the following command in terminal

> sudo scratch-text-editor /etc/rc.local

Add "**sudo rfkill block bluetooth**" command to the line before last. This command will run during start-up of os automatically to disable bluetooth every time you start the system.

To re-enable bluetooth run the following command in terminal

> sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth

And also delete the line added in the rc.local file.

Comment: no need for `sudo' when adding inside rc.local file